# Nodename nor servname provided, or not known for Eureka

Tags: java, spring-cloud, netflix-eureka, netflix-zuul

- I have setup below servers. Following the book spring cloud micro server in action.

  1. Zuul server (port 5555)
  2. Eureka Server(port 8761)
  3. Organization Server(port 8081)
- Now, I'm using this url to get information from license server. localhost:5555/api/organizationservice/v1/organizations/35690f33-71b1-4996-83f8-93b8ca411848/
- This url will get information from organization server though zuul server.
- The problem is the call failed and didn't get any information from organization server.
- OS: Macbook
- Spring boot 2.1.4.RELEASE
- Eureka

```
server.port=8761
eureka.server.wait-time-in-ms-when-sync-empty=5
eureka.client.register-with-eureka=false
eureka.client.fetch-registry=false
```

- Organization

```
server.port=8081
spring.application.name=organizationservice
spring.profiles.active=default
spring.cloud.config.enabled=true
eureka.instance.prefer-ip-address=true
eureka.client.register-with-eureka=true
eureka.client.fetch-registry=true
eureka.client.service-url.defaultZone=http://localhost:8761/eureka/
spring.cloud.config.uri=http://localhost:8888
logging.level.com.chenlin=debug
```

- Zuul

```
server.port=5555
spring.application.name=zuulservice
eureka.instance.prefer-ip-address=true
eureka.client.register-with-eureka=true
eureka.client.fetch-registry=true
eureka.client.service-url.defaultZone=http://localhost:8761/eureka/
zuul.prefix=/api
zuul.routes.organizationservice.serviceId=organizationservice
zuul.routes.organizationservice.path=/organization/**
zuul.routes.licenseingservice.serviceId=licenseingservice
zuul.routes.licenseingservice.path=/licenseing/**
management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=routes
logging.level.com.chenlin=debug
```

log from zuul server.

```
com.netflix.zuul.exception.ZuulException: Forwarding error
    at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.zuul.filters.route.RibbonRoutingFilter.handleException(RibbonRoutingFilter.java:198) ~[spring-cloud-netflix-zuul-2.1.3.RELEASE.jar:2.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.zuul.filters.route.RibbonRoutingFilter.forward(RibbonRoutingFilter.java:173) ~[spring-cloud-netflix-zuul-2.1.3.RELEASE.jar:2.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.zuul.filters.route.RibbonRoutingFilter.run(RibbonRoutingFilter.java:119) ~[spring-cloud-netflix-zuul-2.1.3.RELEASE.jar:2.1.3.RELEASE]
...
Caused by: com.netflix.client.ClientException: null
    at com.netflix.client.AbstractLoadBalancerAwareClient.executeWithLoadBalancer(AbstractLoadBalancerAwareClient.java:118) ~[ribbon-loadbalancer-2.3.0.jar:2.3.0]
    at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.zuul.filters.route.support.AbstractRibbonCommand.run(AbstractRibbonCommand.java:221) ~[spring-cloud-netflix-zuul-2.1.3.RELEASE.jar:2.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.zuul.filters.route.support.AbstractRibbonCommand.run(AbstractRibbonCommand.java:55) ~[spring-...
    at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.zuul.filters.route.RibbonRoutingFilter.forward(RibbonRoutingFilter.java:167) ~[spring-cloud-netflix-zuul-2.1.3.RELEASE.jar:2.1.3.RELEASE]
    ... 64 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.net.UnknownHostException: fe80: nodename nor servname provided, or not known
    at rx.exceptions.Exceptions.propagate(Exceptions.java:57) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar:1.3.8]
    at rx.observables.BlockingObservable.blockForSingle(BlockingObservable.java:463) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar:1.3.8]
    at rx.observables.BlockingObservable.single(BlockingObservable.java:340) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar:1.3.8]
    at com.netflix.client.AbstractLoadBalancerAwareClient.executeWithLoadBalancer(AbstractLoadBalancerAwareClient.java:112) ~[ribbon-loadbalancer-2.3.0.jar:2.3.0]
    ... 126 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: fe80: nodename nor servname provided, or not known
    at java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupAllHostAddr(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_202]
    at java.net.InetAddress$2.lookupAllHostAddr(InetAddress.java:929) ~[na:1.8.0_202]
    at java.net.InetAddress.getAddressesFromNameService(InetAddress.java:1324) ~[na:1.8.0_202]
    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName0(InetAddress.java:1277) ~[na:1.8.0_202]
    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1193) ~[na:1.8.0_202]
    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1127) ~[na:1.8.0_202]
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.SystemDefaultDnsResolver.resolve(SystemDefaultDnsResolver.java:45) ~[httpclient-4.5.8.jar:4.5.8]
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.java:112) ~[httpclient-4.5.8.jar:4.5.8]
```

Use below url can find the organizationservice has been registration successful
http://localhost:8761/eureka/apps/

```
{
    "applications": {
        "versions__delta": "1",
        "apps__hashcode": "UP_3_",
        },
            {
                "name": "ORGANIZATIONSERVICE",
                "instance": [
                    {
                        "instanceId": "ZDMdeMacBook-Pro.local:organizationservice:8081",
                        "hostName": "127.0.0.1",
                        "app": "ORGANIZATIONSERVICE",
                        "ipAddr": "127.0.0.1",
                        "status": "UP",
                        "overriddenStatus": "UNKNOWN",
                        "port": {
                            "$": 8081,
                            "@enabled": "true"
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: Try Disabling ipv6?

Comment: Yes, Thanks for your reminder. This related to network issue. The problem is when I start up the eureka server in a wifi local network. But when I use the url ```localhost:5555/api/organizationservice/v1/organizations/35690f33-71b1-4996-83f8-93b8ca411848/``` to get organization service my pc has been disconnect from that wifi network. So, we can see my hostname is "127.0.0.1" in the eureka info. But in the log the mentioned fe80 ```java.net.UnknownHostException: fe80:```. I can get rid of this issue in 2 ways.

Comment: 1. Restart eureka server in new network environment. Is the simply way.

Comment: 2.Add a mapping for fe80 to 127.0.0.1 or add ZDMdeMacBook-Pro.local to 127.0.0.1. In /private/etc/hosts. Like this: cat /private/etc/hosts to see the hostname mapping and add the new mapping for  ZDMdeMacBook-Pro.local to 127.0.0.1 in vim. And then dscacheutil -flushcache refresh the mapping cache. This problem can be resolved.